# Order by for column in varchar type

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have the following column **strand** which is ordered in ascending order but its taking 3.10 as next after 3.1 instead of 3.2..

the column is  varchar  type..

```
 Strand
 3.1
 3.1.1
 3.1.1.1
 3.1.1.2
 3.1.2
 3.1.2.1
 3.10       # wrong  
 3.10.1     # wrong
 3.10.1.1   # wrong
 3.2        <- this should have been after 3.1.2.1
 3.2.1
 3.2.1.1
 ..
 3.9
 3.9.1.1
         <- here is where 3.10 , 3.10.1 and 3.10.1.1 should reside
```

I used the following query to order it;

```
SELECT * FROM [table1]
ORDER BY RPAD(Strand,4,'.0') ;
```

how to make sure its ordered in the right way such that 3.10,3.10.1 and 3.10.1.1 is at last

Comment: Order by will happen for characters from left to right....... First '3' then '.' then '1 or 2' then '0 or .'

Comment: What is “wrong” here is your understanding of how _string comparison_ works …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE T1;
CREATE TABLE T1 (Strand VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('3.1');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('3.1.1');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('3.1.1.1');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('3.1.1.2');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('3.2');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('3.2.1');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('3.10');
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('3.10.1');

SELECT * FROM T1 
ORDER BY STRAND;


SELECT *
  FROM T1 
  ORDER BY 
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Strand+'.0.0.0.0','.',1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) *1000 +
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Strand,'.0.0.0.0'),'.',2),'.',-1)  AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) *100 +
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Strand,'.0.0.0.0'),'.',3),'.',-1) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) *10 +
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Strand,'.0.0.0.0'),'.',4),'.',-1)  AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

Output not ordeded:

```
    Strand
1   3.1
2   3.1.1
3   3.1.1.1
4   3.1.1.2
5   3.10
6   3.10.1
7   3.2
8   3.2.1
```

Output Ordered:

```
    Strand
1   3.1
2   3.1.1
3   3.1.1.1
4   3.1.1.2
5   3.2
6   3.2.1
7   3.10
8   3.10.1
```

Comment: Sorry, I think now I corrected it (before, I pasted a previous version, without CONCAT on every string)

Answer (score 0):

you can order the result baset on the integer value of your field.  your code will looks like

```
select [myfield]from [mytable] order by 
convert(RPAD(replace([myfield],'.',''),4,0),UNSIGNED INTEGER);
```

in this code replace function will cleand the dots (.)
hope thin help

Comment: Actually you can't. What if you have 3.1.1, 3.1.100, 3.2.1?

Answer (score 0):

You must normalize each group of digits

```
SELECT * FROM [table1]
ORDER BY CONCAT(
    LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Strand,'.',1),3,'0'), '-',
    LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Strand,'.',2),'.',-1),3,'0'), '-',
    LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Strand,'.',3),'.',-1),3,'0'), '-',
    LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Strand,'.',3),'.',-1),3,'0'));
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT CONCAT(
    ->     LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX('3.10.1.1','.',1),3,'0'), '-',
    ->     LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('3.10.1.1','.',2),'.',-1),3,'0'), '-',
    ->     LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('3.10.1.1','.',3),'.',-1),3,'0'), '-',
    ->     LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('3.10.1.1','.',3),'.',-1),3,'0'));
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(
    LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX('3.10.1.1','.',1),3,'0'), '-',
    LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('3.10.1.1','.',2),'.',-1),3,'0'), '-',
    LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX('3.10.1.1','.',3),'.',-1),3,'0'), '-',
    LPAD(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRI |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 003-010-001-001                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the point(`.`) in your data is no more than 3, you can try this:

```
select *
from demo
order by replace(Strand, '.', '') * pow(10, (3 + length(replace(Strand, '.', '')) - length(Strand)))
```

If the point is uncertain, here you can should use subquery to get max num of point:

```
select demo.Strand
from demo
cross join (
    select max(length(Strand) - length(replace(Strand, '.', ''))) as num from demo
) t
order by replace(Strand, '.', '') * pow(10, (num + length(replace(Strand, '.', '')) - length(Strand)))
```

See [**demo**](http://rextester.com/BCUC23017) in Rextester.

As you see, I've used function [`replace`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html), [`length`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_length), [`pow`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_pow) in `order by` clause.

1) `replace(Strand, '.', '')` will give us int number, like:
    `replace('3.10.1.1', '.', '')` => `31011`;
2) `(3 + length(replace(Strand, '.', '')) - length(Strand))` will give us the count of point which the max num of point minus point's count in `Strand`, like:
`3.1` => 2;
3)`pow` returns the value of X raised to the power of Y;

so the sample data will be calculated like:

```
3100
3110
3111
3112
3120
3121
31000
31010
31011
3200
3210
3211
3900
3911
```

by these nums, you will get the right sort.

Answer (score 0):

Cause "strand" column is text data, so it will be ordered in alphabetical. To make it be ordered as your desire, you should format your data before insert or update it. Suppose maximum digit for each level is 3, your data should be formated like this

```
 003.001
 003.001.001
 003.001.001.001
 003.002
 003.002.001
 003.002.001.001
 003.010
 010.001
```

The altenative way is splitting "strand" column into mutiple columns. Each column will store data for each level, such as

```
Level1 | Level2 | Level3 ... 
3      | 1      | 0
3      | 1      | 1
3      | 2      | 0
...
3      | 10     | 0
```

Datatype of these columns should be number and then you should be able to order by these columns.